# Same class name in multiple namespaces in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How to know if there is a class name repeated in different namespaces in Visual Studio? Obviously I'm not looking to test every class name manually.

Comment: You get a compile-error saying either that compiler can´t identify the class or that the name is ambigios.

Comment: Do you mean within a specific assembly that you're testing? You could pretty easily write a unit test to do that with reflection.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: Only if it *is* being used ambiguously. It would be perfectly feasible to create a project which contained the same class name in two different namespaces but without any compile-time errors.

Comment: Disambiguation: I'm not receiving error. I'm looking for a solution to prevent repeating a class name multiple times in a large assembly with multiple namespaces.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: But that's not what the OP was asking for. (And just having `using` directives for both namespaces wouldn't be enough - you'd then have to try to use the type.)

Comment: It is simple to search class name via "Find in files" or other similar ways but I'm looking for a way to check for uniqueness of my defined class names through the assembly.

Comment: Why do you even care about this? Usually you get unambiguity by using the namespaces.

Comment: It is not a check for the uniqueness of the name of a specific class. I look for  a way to check all my class names.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I do get unambiguity but when reorganizing classes among namespaces, I need to be sure that I can move them inside assembly without being afraid of name conflict.

Comment: If you move them use refactoring tools (VS, Resharper, ...) those will fix/alert most issues.

Comment: _I need to be sure that I can move them inside assembly without being afraid of name conflict_ - compiler will tell you faster then unit tests.

Comment: @Fabio You are right but meanwhile automatic renaming can be the source of future headaches.

Comment: Seems little bid odd, that while you are using strong typed programming language, you still need to check for types/classes ambiguity

Comment: No it is not odd. In general you should not be worried about duplicate names. Namespaces have been designed so you can have duplicate type names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd just write a unit test that uses reflection. Something like:

```
var duplicateGroups = typeof(SomeTypeInAssembly).GetTypes()
    .GroupBy(t => t.Name)
    .Where(g => g.Count() != 1);
// Assert that duplicateGroups is empty
```

Exactly how you assert that the collection is empty will depend on your test framework - you'll also want to make sure that when the test *does* fail, it gives you a useful failure message, ideally a list of the types in each group.